# How to read specific values from response

Tags: c#, api

This is the page I'm using for documentation https://lichess.org/api#operation/player
I want to get player usernamename, rating, and title. 
My code.

```
public class Player {
public string username;
public double rating;
public string title;
}

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://lichess.org/");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("player/top/200/bullet").Result;
```

Here I'm getting response, But I have no clue how to take only properties that I need and store it in a list of players.

Comment: If you are downvoting, give at least explanation why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with you on this problem, it was found that the response that you are receiving is a HTML string, therefore you need to deal with this case differently. I was playing around with the `HTML` that you have posted in the comments and I was able to parse the string with `HTML Agility Pack` which can be found [here](https://html-agility-pack.net/). You can also download this pack from the `Nuget Package Manager` in `Visual Studio`.

I am giving you a very basic example of the parsing process that I tried out:

```
public class ProcessHtml()
{
    List<Player> playersList = new List<Player>();

    //Get your HTML loaded from a URL. Giving me SSL exceptions so took a different route
    //var url = "https://lichess.org/player/top/200/bullet";
    //var web = new HtmlWeb();
    //var doc = web.Load(url);

    //Get your HTML loaded as a file in my case
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Downloads\\CkBsZtvf.html", Encoding.UTF8);

    foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody"))
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
        {
            int i = 0;
            Player player = new Player();
            //Since there are 4 rounds per tr, hence get only what is required based on loop condition
            foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
            {                      
                if(i==1)
                {
                    player.username = cell.InnerText;
                }
                if(i==2)
                {
                    player.rating = Convert.ToDouble(cell.InnerText);
                }
                if(i==3)
                {
                    player.title = cell.InnerText;
                }                                              
                i++;
            }
            playersList.Add(player);
        }
    }

    var finalplayerListCopy = playersList;  
}

public class Player 
{
  public string username;
  public double rating;
  public string title;
}
```

After running this, your `finalplayerListCopy` has a count of 200 and an example data would look like:

[image]

Obviously, you would have to play with the data and tailor it as per your need. I hope this helps you out.

Cheers!

Comment: @I.pattern It is working but apparently the way you are parsing your JSON string to your `Player` class is incorrect. Can you show me your JSON string that you are receiving? Maybe it could be: `player= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(result);` .

Comment: I tried but it's not working again. Probably it's not json at all

Comment: @I.pattern Can you show me what response are you getting? It can be a JSON response or a XML response. Let me know what you get.

Comment: @I.pattern Try requesting for `JSON` data. Add this line to your headers: `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";`. Let me know if you get a `JSON` response otherwise, we would need to parse the html structure into what is required for your variables.

Comment: still, it's not json response

Comment: @I.pattern Okay. So now we need to parse our html structure into what is required. Can you show me your html response (no image) so I can see what to do for it.

Comment: No, I have no idea

Comment: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

from what Ive read from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

```
async Task<Player> getPlayerAsync(string path)
{
    Player player= null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        player = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Player>();
    }
    return player;
}
getPlayerAsync("https://lichess.org/player/top/200/bullet");
```